# Is vsee support mobile browsers?

Tags: php, android, mobile, web, real-time

I want to any way realtime video communication via mobile browsser.
I come across vsee is it supports mobile browser real-time communication ?
please let me.

Answer (score 0):

vsee has an API that allows mobile app/browser to launch vsee; however, the API is only released for iPad.  our iPhone client is ~2 months away and Android later this year.  thanks!

Comment: can v develop mobile browser based video chat app without even if mobile browser don't support WEBRTC?